# Display by highest value in multiple fields?

Tags: qgis

I am categorizing parcels based on the highest value across three fields (which represent 3 questions from a survey). So :

if you answered field/question A: 1, field/question B: 3, and field/question C: 4, then I want to categorize/display "4";

if you answered 5,1,1 then I want to display "5".

Working in QGIS and am admittedly not experienced, and have no clue how to make that work.

Answer (score 3):

Choose a categorised symbology based on the following formula:

`max("field A","field B","field C")`

This formula also works for labels, and in both cases only for numeric values.